# In docker, how do I know which image belongs to a given source?

Tags: docker

Im very new to docker but have a question.

Suppose I have 50 images, which I can see from

```
> docker images

p25235 
1566 
p6462263
etc...
```

and 50 projects in folders, which I can see from

```
> ls -la

project1
project2
project3
...etc
```

Is there a way to (quickly | easily) tell which image is associated with which project?

Comment: What is your "project" meaning? Docker image doesn't have any "project" attribute.

Comment: Ok, say I dumped 50 docker images on you, then told you to find the ONE that matches up to a specific folder full of source code. How would you do that?

Comment: How does it matter which folder? Once image is created, it is independent. Just like an image is pulled from docker hub. Is your question something different?

Comment: You just learned a life lesson: tag your images, so you know what they are!

Comment: Tags were the thing I didnt know about. Knew there had to be some mechanism. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Docker images include the their build [history](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/) which line up with the commands in your Dockerfile, as well as any Dockerfiles the image was built `FROM`.

```
docker history <image>
```

Which outputs each layer in the opposite order to your Dockerfile, so the final command is at the top.

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
aa04370cd0c1        4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["-c" "/etc/apt-cacher   0 B                 
ff0286e20caa        4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apt   0 B                 
491d08e75e82        4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/var/cache/apt-cac   0 B                 
66e9f89cab13        4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 3142/tcp              0 B                 
9cc110ba4de6        4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:dfc25768a29b1c296   38 B                
0df0917c94dd        4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:0c3cad42682758b40   3.261 kB            
f0b1119fd676        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -uex;     apt-get update -y;     15.95 MB            
ddf73f48a05d        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0 B                 
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:c6c23585ab140b0b32   123 MB
```

Separating multiple images of the same Dockerfile is a bit harder as normally only the checksums for the image and the build steps will change, unless you have some type of version metadata that is injected into the build.