# How to map docker images to a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Asking this question out of curiosity:

Is it possible to map the docker images and Dockerfiles if they are available in the same machine/server ?

If not is there any way to tag an image which can refer to the Dockerfile ...something of this sort ?

My requirement is know how the images are formed from the docker files if I have images of following sort:

```
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:~/RAGHU/DOCKER# docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
env_path                    1.1                 01502209b2fc        13 minutes ago      187.9 MB
env_path                    1.0                 3610243625cd        14 minutes ago      187.9 MB
env_path                    1.2                 3610243625cd        14 minutes ago      187.9 MB
env_path                    2.0                 c6d1eb2cff1b        14 minutes ago      187.9 MB
```

Comment: `docker history <image>` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40392486/1318694

Comment: for future builds http://label-schema.org looks like a useful standard for attaching meta data to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach to achieve what you requested, is using the [LABEL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) field in your Dockerfile to save the path or an id of your dockerfiles. Then, you could use the `docker inspect` [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) in order to retrieve this information.

You can find more information about labels and how to manage them in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/labels-custom-metadata/).